# How to interpret "in the three years we lived in this house"?

Tags: meaning

Was watching movie Unbreakable, and there were these two sentences. I was a bit confused whether interpret it as the 3/5 years already passed or that it is just the 3rd/5th year still going.

> A. You have been working here for 5 years and never been sick!
>   B. Audrey, do you remember me ever getting sick? In the three years we lived in this house?

How am I supposed to understand this? That the 3 years / 5 years have already passed or that it is almost 3/5 years so that it is just 3rd year he lives here / 5th year he is working somewhere.

Thank you

Comment: Note that the two sentences are not in the same scene. In the first scene, he asked someone at work if he had ever taken any sick leave. In the second scene, he asked Audrey, his wife, while they were at home.

Answer (score 1):

It *could* mean a lot of things. This is usually to indicate a period of time that may have passed or is in the very near future.

Generally if I am using a statement like this it'll mean that it is closer to that number of years than it is to any other number of years.

For example, if I started a job in January 2014, I would say

> I have been in this job for 3 years now.

If I started a job in February 2014 I would say

> I have been in this job for *almost* 3 years now

People sometimes will exaggerate these numbers, for example, if they have lived somewhere for 14 years they may bump the number to 15 even though they have only lived there for 14 years. Some people may not say almost, and the if the period of time is longer, e.g, if it was almost 27 years, it is more likely to be referenced to more vaguely, for example:

> 27 years
>
> almost 30 years
>
> over 25 years

The main point is that it is approximately that period of time since the first event, whether is is moving into a house, starting a job, getting married or anything else.